# Attempting to drop columns in Excel files

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have 142 files i am attempting to modify to remove four columns and add six. Please see the code below

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

source_folder = os.path.abspath(r'source folder')

dest_folder = os.path.abspath(r'destination folder')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(source_folder):
    for file in files:
        path_file=os.path.join(folder, file)
        if path_file in os.listdir(dest_folder):
            print(path_file+" exists.")
            
    else:
        df=pd.read_excel(path_file)
        df.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.drop(columns=["FIND"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.drop(columns=["*"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 9"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.insert(4,"Parent","")
        df.insert(5,"Type","")
        df.insert(6,"Drawing Number","")
        df["Drawing Missing"]=""
        df["Logo Change Required"]=""
        df["HSE Impact"]=""
        df.to_excel(path_file)
```

There are two errors I am running into: the first is that the referenced columns I need dropped cannot be found. I have verified that they exist, but I always receive this as an error: **KeyError: "['Unnamed: 9'] not found in axis"** I believe I have the df.drop lines setup correctly, but I may be missing something simple.

The second is that the file will not be written to the destination folder. I have commented out the df.drop lines and adding the columns works, but it will only save it back to the original location.

Thanks for the help.

20NOV2020 - Update: Per suggestion below, I tried on one file and it does work as expected. Possibly something in my IF/ELSE or path_file variable.

30NOV2020 - I may have found the issue. Not all of the files have the columns that I am looking to delete, so it is freezing the program. I will probably need to add something in to skip if the column does not exist.

Comment: in **df=pd.read_excel(path_file)** use example `df=pd.read_excel('c:\\user\\...\\file.xlsx')`

Comment: @Salio - It worked on the example file. So must be something in my folder walk, which would be why my troublehooting did not work. I have previously used that portion of the code to sort like type files. Might need to specify file type even though there are only .xlsx type files in the folder. Thanks.

Comment: @Salio - Troubleshooting didnt work, I will update the topic.